# snellen and sloan fonts are flipped/mirrored

Tags: fonts, font-forge

I've downloaded the Snellen and Sloan fonts distributed on [this website](http://radagast.ca/snellen/snellen.html).
I'm on Linux Fedora. I've saved the fonts on ~/.fonts and the fonts are available to my applications (Inkscape, Libreoffice).

However, when I insert text the fonts are mirrored (flipped horizzontally).
I guess that the font is built incorrectly... Should the mirrored fonts have their own "style"?
Perhaps I should create two styles (or families) within each font using Fontforge?

As you can imagine, I know nothing on the subject, so any hint is appreciated.

Comment: A very odd behaviour. Perhaps this question is more suitable for http://unix.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: Why on Unix? I can reproduce the problem even on Windows.

Comment: Please update your question and be more specific. As Max says in his answer, the behaviour is correct.

Comment: I've added that I was using lowerletter cases. That was the problem.. even if the answer by Max already explained that. I feel always a stranger in these stackexchange forums...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The linked font contains the "normal" glyphs as uppercase letters and mirrored copies as lowercase.

[image: Snellen ttf preview]

Comment: Indeed. The reason for that is because some eye tests want you to point out the open end of the letter E. By providing both normal and inverse characters, it's easier to create such tests.

Comment: I was entering lowercase letters and I did not even try uppercase. Of course I will use the uppercase letters for an eye chart.

Comment: @PieBie Are you referring to the [tumbling E chart](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E_chart)? In that chart the open end of letter E can be left, down, up or down.I think that these mirrored fonts may be used along with the software distributed in the website I've linked in my first email.